# Solving an equation involving an integral

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

How do I get the following into *Mathematica*, solving for $a$:

$$ 0.7 = 1 - \frac{2}{a} \times \left[ \frac{1}{a} \int_0^a \frac{x}{\exp(x)-1}\mathrm dx + \frac{a}{6} - 1\right] $$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: In particular, it is helpful to let us know what you have already tried? This site does not provide tutorial services. I would suggest first trying to evaluate `Integrate[(x/(Exp[x] - 1)), {x, 0, a}]` and see what that answer suggests to you. You can then use `NSolve` or maybe `FindRoot` to work out the rest.

Comment: Thanks Verbeia. Can you tell me what the following won't return the Reals result and gives me back an equation?:

   'NSolve[1 - (2/
      a)*((1/a)*Integrate[(x/(Exp[x] - 1)), {x, 0, a}] + (a/6) - 1) ==
   0.7, a, Reals]'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my experience FindRoot works best for such problems:

```
In[1]:= fun[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(x/(Exp[x] - 1)), {x, 0, a}]

In[2]:= FindRoot[1 - (2/a)*((1/a)*fun[a] + (a/6) - 1) == 0.7, {a, 0.1}]

Out[2]= {a -> 58.3073}
```

Answer (score 3):

One can also use the event detection capability (`WhenEvent[]`) of `NDSolve[]` to find the desired root:

```
(* (Exp[x] - 1)/x; see http://books.google.com/books?id=7J52J4GrsJkC&pg=PA20 *)
exm1x[x_?NumberQ] := With[{t = Exp[x], one = N[1, Precision[x]]}, 
                          Piecewise[{{one, t == 1}}, (t - 1)/Log[t]]]

NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == 1/exm1x[x], y[0] == 0, 
             WhenEvent[7 x^2/10 == x^2 - 2 (y[x] + x^2/6 - x), "StopIntegration",
                       "DetectionMethod" -> Interpolation,
                       "LocationMethod" -> "Brent"]},
             y["Domain"], {x, 0, ∞}, Method -> "Extrapolation",
             AccuracyGoal -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 20][[1, -1]]
   58.307312765209898828
```

Answer (score 2):

The integral has an exact representation, so it's possible to use several methods.

```
fun[a_] = Integrate[(x/(Exp[x] - 1)), {x, 0, a}, Assumptions -> a > 0]
(*  -(a^2/2) + I a π - π^2/6 + a Log[-1 + E^a] + PolyLog[2, E^a]  *)

FindRoot[1 - (2/a)*((1/a)*fun[a] + (a/6) - 1) == 7/10, {a, 1}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
(*  {a -> 58.307312765239769644}  *)

NSolve[1 - (2/a)*((1/a)*fun[a] + (a/6) - 1) == 7/10 && 50 < a < 60, a,
  WorkingPrecision -> 20]
(*  {{a -> 58.307312765239769644}}  *)
```

Of course, to use `NSolve` you need to give it a compact domain, so one needs some knowledge of where the root is.

Or if you want an exact representation,

```
sol = Root[{
  1 - (2/a)*((1/a)*fun[a] + (a/6) - 1) == 7/10 /. 
     Equal -> Subtract /. a -> # // Function[bdy, bdy &],
  a /. FindRoot[1 - (2/a)*((1/a)*fun[a] + (a/6) - 1) == 7/10, {a, 1}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 20]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
N[sol, 50]
(*  58.307312765239769643612756575305892317507739080842 + 0.*10^-49 I  *)
```

Comment: I'm seeing a number of questions involving Debye-like functions lately. I wonder why...

Comment: @J.M. I have no idea.  This is a somewhat older question, though.